# TypeScript 2.1 Interface Merging with import from

Tags: typescript, export, declaration

I have an extension for the Window interface, looks like this:

```
import IStuff from "Stuff/IStuff";

interface Window {
  Stuff: IStuff;
}

export default Window;
```

I want to use the Stuff extension in a different file by importing the file above like this:

```
import Window from WindowExtension;

class StuffApp {

  public doStuff() {
    window.Stuff.doStuff();

  }

}
```

The compiler fails with "Property 'Stuff' does not exists on type 'Window'; What am I doing wrong? Also, it is very important to be able to use this extension somehow from other projects.

Thanks, guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code *does not extend the global window*

```
import IStuff from "Stuff/IStuff";

interface Window {
  Stuff: IStuff;
}

export default Window;
```

It actually exports a *new window interface* as the file is a module (because of the import). More https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/project/modules.html

## Proper fix

```
import IStuff from "Stuff/IStuff";



  interface MyWindow extends Window {
    Stuff: IStuff;
  }


export default (window as MyWindow)
```

And then use

```
import MyWindow from WindowExtension;

class StuffApp {

  public doStuff() {
    MyWindow.Stuff.doStuff();

  }

}
```